# Create overlap floating action bottom

Tags: android

How can I create overlap floating action bottom like this image
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BottomAppBar` in `CoordinatorLayout` & set the anchor to your FAB.

In your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In your `menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/miHome"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="Home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/miSearch"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="Search" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/placeholder"
        android:title="" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/miProfile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_person"
        android:title="Profile" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/miSettings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:title="Settings" />
</menu>
```

It is important to have that placeholder because that's where we'll overlap our FAB.

In you activity disable the placeholder item & let FAB take focus:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavigationView)
        bottomNavigationView.background = null
        bottomNavigationView.menu.getItem(2).isEnabled = false
    }

}
```